# why I can find the value of y'[x] through the ?Global`*

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

y'[x]=x E^-y[x];

?Global`*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSClH.png)

Answer (score 0):

`y'[x]` is equivalent to `Derivative[1][y][x]`

so you can find the assignment on `Derivative`

```
y'[x] = x E^-y[x];
SubValues[Derivative]
```

> {HoldPattern[Derivative[1][y][x]] :> E^-y[x] x}

`Derivative` is a variable in the `System` context. See info using `?? Derivative`.

Another example to show the same applies, but not using a system variable

```
example[1][r] = a b c;
SubValues[example]
```

> {HoldPattern[example[1][r]] :> a b c}

`example` is in the `Global` context -- see `?? example`